# Qt: How to use QGraphicsItemAnimation for multiple items

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem

I am trying to control multiple items animation by using QGraphicsItemAnimation. For my understanding of QGraphicsItemAnimation, i shall have a QTimeline and several QGraphicsItems which control by QGraphicsItemAnimation.

At first, i did not use the QGraphicsItemAnimation, but only QTimeline, and connect QTimeline and QGraphicsItem.

Like this:

```
connect(timeLine, SIGNAL(valueChanged(qreal)), graphicsItem, SLOT(scale(qreal)));

void GraphicsItem::scale(qreal value)
{
        setTransform(QTransform()
                     .translate(mZoomFactor.x(), mZoomFactor.y())
                     .scale(value + 1, value + 1)
                     .translate(-mZoomFactor.x(), -mZoomFactor.y()));
}
```

But using this way make the animation look like lose frame.
So i referred the Qt example, however QGraphicsItemAnimation do not provide such function like `setTransformAt()` or `setOpacityAt()`. Is there any Qt example for complex animation?

Comment: For this situation, i have to use the QPropertyAnimation?

Comment: By the way, QGraphicsPixmapItem could not resize?